# R: Legends on ggtern plot

Tags: r, ggtern

I want to use the R package ggtern to plot two sets of data. But I don't know how to add different colors and legends to the plot. Could anyone helps? Thank you.

```
library(ggtern)

a <- data.frame(x=c(0.1,0.9,0),
            y=c(0.4,0.2,0.4),
            z=c(0.3,0.4,0.3))

b <- data.frame(x=c(0.5,0.5,0),
    y=c(0.4,0.4,0.2),
    z=c(0.5,0.3,0.2))

df = rbind(a,b) 

ggtern(data=df,aes(x,y,z)) +
    geom_point()
```

Comment: See e.g. http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/ for how to add colors to `ggplot` graphs (which `ggtern` makes). It's unclear what specifically you want to do here.

Comment: I am quite clear that I want to make different colors and legends here. I am new to ggtern. Your answer is not clear to me.

Comment: What would you like to have in different colors?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you are after?

```
library(ggtern)
a <- data.frame(series = "A",
                x=c(0.1,0.9,0),
                y=c(0.4,0.2,0.4),
                z=c(0.3,0.4,0.3))

b <- data.frame(series = "B",
                x=c(0.5,0.5,0),
                y=c(0.4,0.4,0.2),
                z=c(0.5,0.3,0.2))
df = rbind(a,b)
ggtern(data=df,aes(x,y,z,color=series)) +
  theme_bw() + geom_mask() +
  geom_point()
```

Producing this:

[image: Output]